# LDAP server which is my base dn

Tags: authentication, ldap, openca

Hello I'm trying to use my ldap test server in order to authenticate users in openca.

I'm currently connecting through phpldapadmin with :

> Login DN : cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
>   Password : mypass

but on openca something is going wrong... in datasources.xml I found the settings of the ldap configuration and it asks for

```
<name>basedn</name>
```

which is the basedn for me ? I already tried

```
cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
```

and

```
dc=example,dc=com
```

I can connect to my ldap with LDAP Admin explorer too.

Thanks !

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The base dn is `dc=example,dc=com`.

I don't know about openca, but I will try this answer since you got very little traffic so far.

A base dn is the point from where a server will search for users. So I would try to simply use `admin` as a login name.

If openca behaves like most ldap aware applications, this is what is going to happen :

1. An ldap search for the user `admin` will be done by the server starting at the base dn (`dc=example,dc=com`).
2. When the user is found, the full dn (`cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`) will be used to bind with the supplied password.
3. The ldap server will hash the password and compare with the stored hash value. If it matches, you're in.

Getting step 1 right is the hardest part, but mostly because we don't get to do it often. Things you have to look out for in your configuraiton file are :

- The `dn` your application will use to bind to the ldap server. This happens at application startup, before any user comes to authenticate. You will have to supply a full dn, maybe something like `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`.
- The authentication method. It is usually a "simple bind".
- The user search filter. Look at the attribute named `objectClass` for your `admin` user. It will be either `inetOrgPerson` or `user`. There will be others like `top`, you can ignore them. In your openca configuration, there should be a string like `(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)`. Whatever it is, make sure it matches your admin user's object Class. You can specify two object class with this search filter `(|(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=user))`.

Download an LDAP Browser, such as [Apache's Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/). Connect using your application's credentials, so you will see what your application sees.

Comment: I was setting up LDAP using some other tools following similar tutorials as OP. I found out that the dn for my Admin account was "cn=admin,cn=users,dc=example,dc=com". So it's possible that you would have to set the base name to "cn=users,dc=example,dc=com"

Answer (score 0):

Either you set LDAP_DOMAIN variable or you misconfigured it. Jump inside of ldap machine/container and run:

```
slapcat > backup.ldif
```

If it fails, check punctuation, quotes etc while you assigned variable "LDAP_DOMAIN"
Otherwise you will find answer inside on backup.ldif file.