# Configure GitLab with open LDAP

Tags: git, ldap, gitlab, openldap

I am trying to configure my `gitlab` with `openldap` to authenticate the users. I have configured the openldap and it is working fine with `Jenkins`. But with `gitlab` it is giving the error that `Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials".`

Below are the `gitlab.rb` configs:

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS' # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'LDAP'
     host: 'localhost'
     port: 389
     uid: 'uid'
     method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
     bind_dn: 'cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com'
     password: 'waqas'
     active_directory: false
     allow_username_or_email_login: true
    #block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'cn=Appliance,dc=ldap,dc=com'
     user_filter: ''
# attributes:
#   username: ['uid', 'userid', 'sAMAccountName']
#   email:    ['mail', 'email', 'userPrincipalName']
#   name:       'cn'
#       first_name: 'givenName'
#       last_name:  'sn'
#     ## EE only
#    group_base: 'ou=W-Integrate,dc=ldap,dc=com'
     #admin_group: 'cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com'
#     sync_ssh_keys: false
#

 EOS
```

[image]
And My openLDAP screen shoot is also attached. can any one correct me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did it work just by modifying the base dn?

Comment: Yes, it work like a charm..thanks

Comment: \o/, or rather: ٩(｡•́‿•̀｡)۶

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base should not be a user (or `inetOrgPerson`, group of users `cn=Appliance`), it should be limited to [`dc` entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756876/6309) for [a base dn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016551/6309):

```
base: 'dc=ldap,dc=com'
```

This differ from `bind_dn`, the binding account, which does reference a user:  `bind_dn: 'cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com'`: there is a `cn` there.

---

Note that since [GitLab 13.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/12/22/gitlab-13-7-released/#support-for-encrypted-ldap-credentials) (December 2020):

> ### Support for encrypted LDAP credentials
>
> GitLab uses a unified configuration file, for example `gitlab.rb` in Omnibus GitLab, which makes configuration easy across all of the bundled services.
>
> Included in this configuration file are some secrets, like the
> credentials to authenticate to the LDAP server.
> While access to this file does require elevated privileges, best practice
> is to separate secrets from configuration.
>
> Omnibus GitLab and Source installs now support [encrypted credentials](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/encrypted_configuration.html), with the first credential supported being LDAP.
> This reduces the sensitivity of the GitLab configuration file, and also helps to achieve customer compliance requirements.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/index.html#using-encrypted-credentials) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/238483).

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution for openLDAP:
   create a group with groupOfUniqueNames instead of groupOfNames because only groupOfUniqueNames has memberOf attribute by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).